# Sending Email in Laravel Using Swift Mailer without Gmail

Tags: laravel-4, swiftmailer

Hello i'm new to laravel and still getting familiar with certain features, i would like to know how i can send an email from my laravel application without using gmail smtp settings.  Like the way the mail function works in basic PHP. Is this possible? I have tried googling it but i have been unable to find a solution, they all use gmail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your app/config/mail.php
change driver, host and from

```
'driver' => 'mail',
'host' => '',
'from' => array('address' => 'us@example.com', 'name' => 'Laravel'),
```

or you can set 'from' within

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
});
```

Comment: When i tried it this way no more error, is there a reason for this? Why didn't sendgrid and mailgun work? Or is it because i'm using my localhost?